# using node.js how to find the returned value is string or [object]

Tags: jquery, node.js

Using node.js how can i detect the returned value is `string` or `[object][object]`

My `jobObj` some times returns  `[object][object]`
so i have to check to know which values is coming like string or [object] and have to do some operations based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `typeof` unary operator:

```
if (typeof jobObj === 'string') {
  //it's a string
else {
  //it's not a string
}
```